# how can I concatinate an atribute name with 'this' in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

```
populateSelect: function (selectID, INPUT, VALUE, TEXT) {

        var JSONstring = JSON.stringify(INPUT, '/', '');
        var items = JSON.parse(JSONstring);
        var $selectElement = $("#"+selectID);

        $(items).each(function () {
            var newOption = '<option value="' + this + '.' + VALUE + '">' + this + '.' + TEXT + '</option>';
            $selectElement.append(newOption);
        });
    }
selectId = #someSelectBox
INPUT = JSON obj
VALUE = someID
TEXT = someName
this.catId 
this.catName
//catId and catName will be send via parameters.
```

I want to create general function to populate selector's options.
where i just pass JSON, select box id, value and text.
there many attributes in JSON so i want to select specific attribute.

Comment: What is your JSON object? Without seeing it we would not know what `$(item)` is selecting.

Comment: {[{"subCatId":3,"catId":5,"subCatName":"test","subCatCode":"1234","subCatDescription":"test","subCatIsActive":true,"subCatCreatedBy":"Awais","subCatCreatedOn":"2016-04-11T02:57:52.587","subCatModifyBy":null,"subCatModifyOn":null},{"subCatId":4,"catId":5,"subCatName":"test","subCatCode":"1234","subCatDescription":"test","subCatIsActive":true,"subCatCreatedBy":"Awais","subCatCreatedOn":"2016-04-11T02:57:56.563","subCatModifyBy":null,"subCatModifyOn":null}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make you options DOM like :

```
var newOption = '<option value="' + this['"+VALUE+"'] +  '">' + this['"+TEXT+"'] + '</option>';
```

it will automatically pickup the key of your object from current object.

Comment: one correction here. no need to concatenate like this 'this['"+VALUE+"']' this simply with 'this[VALUE]'